# Will mathematicians ever define zero as denominator?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, math-history

As you all know, Zero as a denominator is a no-go in maths. I always wonder if this could ever change.

For example you can’t use negative integers in the root but mathematicians defined complex numbers to “bypass” this hurdle, although the “bypassing” is a somehow exaggeration but I hope, you get what I mean!

I wonder if we could define the “super complex numbers “ , such as one devided by zero, equals to 1 over i. I am not sure if 1 over i would get in trouble with the notations of complex numbers!

Comment: [Wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) is a topic you might want to read up on.

Comment: With [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number), you can't divide by *zero*, but you can divide by an infinitesimal ($\epsilon$) to get an infinity ($\omega$).

Comment: $\frac{1}{i}=-i$. Consider $\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ which has a removable singularity at $x=0$: $sinc(0)=1$.

Comment: You don't have to wait for us (?) to define it. **You** can do it yourself — and deal with the consequences!

Comment: Another one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere ... The problem is not "Do not divide by zero".  The problem is "Do not divide by zero in the real number system".  Other systems may allow dividing by zero.

Answer (score 1):

In $p$-adics we can consider divisions where the divisor is not multiplicatively invertible. Such divisions arise in the context of $p$- adic logarithms.

Suppose we seek a solution to the equation $2^x=3$ in $5$-adics. Strictly speaking, there is no solution because the exponent, to be determined below, gives powers of $2$ that do not converge uniformly to $3$; they actually form four subsequences that separately converge to $3\zeta$ for each fourth of unity $\zeta$. To remove this complication we take fourth powers, so that $16^x=81$.

We then render

$x=\dfrac{\ln 81}{\ln 16}$

and apply the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$, which converges $p$-adically whenever $x$ is a multiple of $p$ for any odd prime $p$. This gives, using base 5 arithmetic:

$\ln(311)=...02010$

$\ln(31)=...10330$

Now, despite the denominator having a terminal zero and thus it lacks a multiplicative inverse, the $5$-adic equation

$...10330x=...02010$

does have a unique solution, which is obtained by canceling terminal zeroes and using ordinary division:

$...1033x=...0201$

$x=...1412.$

(Note the price we pay: we have lost a "digit" from our logarithm calculations.) Switching back to base 10, this derivation says that $16^x\equiv81\bmod5^5$ when $x\equiv232\bmod5^4$. To retrieve our original equation $2^x=3$, we must separately apply the correct residue modulo 4 ($x\equiv3$), so we find that $2^x\equiv3\bmod5^5$ when $x\equiv2107\bmod(4×5^4)$.